# Java. containsAll для списка массивов

Tags: java

Есть список, состоящий из массивов `ArrayList<int[]>  list1;`. 
И второй список поменьше `ArrayList<int[]>  list2;`.

Но чтобы сравнить, содержит ли список `list1` в себе `list2`, такая запись почему-то не работает:

```
list1.containsAll(list2);
```

всегда выдает `false`, даже если заранее знать, что `list1` содержит в себе `list2`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что Вас может не устроить логика работы метода `containsAll()` по умолчанию.

Поэтому, предлагаю переопределить методы на те, которые Вам нужны по сути работы.

Ниже пример реализации своего сравнения `ArrayList<int[]>` с логикой сравнения по значениям без учета последовательности.

Кстати, сам метод `containsAll()` мы не переопределяем, т.к. его реализация в классе `ArrayList` нас устраивает. То есть метод containsAll() вызывает последовательно метод contains() для каждого элемента списка. Соответственно нам нужно переопределить только метод contains(), чтобы добиться нужной нам логики работы.

**Ниже класс MyArrayList**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<int[]> {

    /*переопределяем метод contains(), потому что метод containsAll()
      будет вызывать метод contains()
    для каждого объекта списка ArrayList.
    */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        int[] arr = (int[])o;

        //сортируем входящий массив "o" по значениям.
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        //каждый объекта нашего списка "this" сравниваем с объектом "o".
        for (int[] i : this) {
            //сортируем выбранный массив "i" по значениям.
            Arrays.sort(i);

            //Сравниваем два массива "i" и "o" по содержимому.
            if(Arrays.toString(i).compareTo(Arrays.toString(arr)) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*если заданный отсортированный массив "o" не был найден
          ни в одном массиве списка "this", то contains()=false
        */
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Ниже класс Application для тестирования**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        List<int[]> list1 = new MyArrayList();
        List<int[]> list2 = new MyArrayList();
        List<int[]> list3 = new MyArrayList();

        list1.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        list1.add(new int[]{9, 4, 5, 6});
        list1.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});

        list2.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});
        list2.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});

        list3.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        list3.add(new int[]{4, 5, 55, 6});

        System.out.println("containsAll() list2 in list1 = " + list1.containsAll(list2));
        System.out.println("containsAll() list3 in list1 = " + list1.containsAll(list3));
    }
}
```

**Результат запуска этого примера ниже:**

```
containsAll() list2 in list1 = true
containsAll() list3 in list1 = false
```

**Описание:**

То есть все отсортированные массивы в списке `list2` содержатся в отсортированных массивах списка `list1`, поэтому наш переопределенный метод `containsAll()` вернул `true`.

Но для `list3` `containsAll()` вернул `false`, потому что не все отсортированные массивы в списке `list3` содержатся в отсортированных массивах списка `list1`.

Comment: ОГО! Я несколько по другому планировал решить эту задачку, а тут готовое решение с написанным кодом, да и ещё протестированное. Огромное СПАСИБО! Обязательно воспользуюсь.

Comment: Только учтите один нюанс, что здесь идет сортировка массивов через sort(), которые (массивы) являются объектами ваших списков. Если последовательность элементов в массивах нарушать нельзя, то надо немного доработать код.

Comment: Этот нюанс я учел и вместо сортировки + `compareTo` использую `Arrays.equals(i, this)`

Answer (score 9):

Принцип работы метода `collectionA.containsAll(collectionB)` состоит в следующем:

> Для каждого элемента коллекции B происходит проверка на его
>   принадлежность коллекции А.

Проверка эта заключается в следующем:

> Берется один элемент B и в цикле сравнивается с каждым элементом
>   коллекции А.

Причем сравнение идет с помощью метода **`equals`**.
У вас в коллекциях содержатся массивы. У массивов метод `equals` **не переопределен**. Таким образом, будет использоваться метод `equals` от класса Object, который даст `true` только в том случае, если обе ссылки будут ссылаться на один и тот же массив в памяти.
Это все равно, что сравнивать массивы через оператор `==`. В вашем случае в разных коллекциях у вас лежат разные массивы, которые никогда не дадут `true` при вызове метода `equals`

Comment: Примерно так я и предполагал. Но вопрос остается открытым. Как сравнить содержание списков если элементы этих списков - массивы.

Comment: Олег, посмотрите мой ответ с реализацией класса MyArrayList.

Comment: А можно уточняющий вопрос? Я так понимаю, что 'remove()', и .'removeAll()' также используют метод 'contains()', что бы понять что удалять?

Comment: @Олег, remove() идет по коллекции и проверяет, если элемент equals() текущему в коллекции, то он удаляет. А вот removeAll() сначала проверяет, contains() ли элемент в коллекции и если да, то удаляет его. В любом случае все сходится к equals()

Comment: Не обязательно все сводится к equals(), по крайней мере не к дефалтовому equals(). В своем ответе, я переопределил contains(). После этого, equals() перестал для меня что-то значить.

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev я имею ввиду стандартную реализацию